# Stored procedure to insert new values into the class table

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is homework.

The goal is to create a stored procedure which will insert new values into the class table. If the `end_date` is prior to the `start_date`, then the stored procedure needs to add two weeks to the start date by default.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_class(
  Teacher_name_param       class.teacher_name%TYPE,
  class_name_param         class.class_name%TYPE,
  Start_Date_param         class.start_date%TYPE,
  End_date_param           class.end_date%TYPE,
  class_category_param     class.class_category%TYPE,
  Topic_param              class.topic%TYPE,
  Teacher_credential_param class.teacher_credential%TYPE)
AS
  class_number_var class.class_number%TYPE;
  --start_date_var class.start_date%TYPE; 
  end_date_var     class.end_date%TYPE;

  BEGIN
    -- Creates the next ID 
    SELECT class_number_seq.NEXTVAL
    INTO class_number_var
    FROM dual;

    IF end_date_param < start_date_param THEN
      SELECT end_date_param INTO end_date_var
      FROM class
      WHERE class_number_var = class.class_number;
      end_date_var := start_date_param + 14;
    ELSE
      end_date_var := end_date_param;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO class (class_number, teacher_name, class_name, start_date, end_date,
                       class_category, topic, teacher_credential)
    VALUES (class_number_var, teacher_name_param, class_name_param, start_date_param, end_date_param,
            class_category_param, topic_param, teacher_credential_param);

    COMMIT;
  END;
/
```

Example call statement:

```
CALL insert_class('Collin Hannah', 'Intro to psychology', 01-OCT-15, 01-SEP-15, 'Psychology', 'Intro Classes', 'BS psychology');
```

1. This looks like solid logic to me. I get a "procedure insert_class" compiled message. However, when I try to call the procedure, I get an error message `not a valid function or procedure name`.
2. I'm assuming that `end_date_var` will take the place of the `end_date_param` if the original end_date_param value is before the start_date_param. Is this correct? If I try to place both end_date_var and end_date_param in the `VALUES` portion of the `INSERT INTO` statement, it throws the entire thing off of balance.

Comment: `01-OCT-15` is not a valid date literal. Please read the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Comment: Your issue is with the syntax you are using to execute the procedure. `CALL` is not a valid syntax. Also, as already said, `01-OCT-15` is not a valid DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It seems procedure is good from compilation end. Just to add always put date format properly as illuistrated below. Lte me know if this helps.

```
BEGIN
  insert_class('Collin Hannah', 'Intro to psychology', TO_DATE('01-OCT-15','DD-MON-YY'), TO_DATE('01-SEP-15','DD-MON-YY'), 'Psychology', 'Intro Classes', 'BS psychology');
END;

--OR

EXEC insert_class('Collin Hannah', 'Intro to psychology', TO_DATE('01-OCT-15','DD-MON-YY'), TO_DATE('01-SEP-15','DD-MON-YY'), 'Psychology', 'Intro Classes', 'BS psychology');
```

Answer (score 0):

> CALL insert_class
>
> not a valid function or procedure name

**CALL** is not a valid syntax to execute the **procedure**. You need to either **EXECUTE** in SQL*Plus, or call it in a **PL/SQL** block.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p
  2  as
  3  begin
  4  null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
```

Procedure is created.

**Error reproduce**

```
SQL> CALL p;
CALL p
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

**Correct way**

```
SQL> EXEC p;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also,

> 01-OCT-15

`01-OCT-15` is not a valid **DATE**. You should either use **TO_DATE** or **ANSI Date literal** to explicitly convert a literal into date.

For example,

```
TO_DATE('01-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

Remember, **TO_DATE** is **NLS** dependent.

Since, you are not concerned with the time portion, I would prefer using **ANSI Date literal** which uses a fixed date format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

For example,

```
DATE '2015-10-01'
```